# macOS - Find all sites where a password is used?

Tags: macos, passwords, keychain

I know that one of my passwords was compromised. I would like to search in my keychain/icloud-keychain all sites where that password is used so I can replace it. How can I do that? I know how to find by site name or username, but not by password...

Answer (score 2):

Safari 14 has this feature built-in. I believe it works on anything stored in your keychain as type "Internet password" or "Web form password", even if they came from other browsers that use the Keychain the standard way.

In Safari, go Safari > Preferences > Passwords. The fourth (unlabeled) column displays a yellow exclamation-point-in-a-triangle icon if that password is reused or easily guessed.

Safari 14 is out as a free update for at macOS 10.15.x Catalina, and possibly other versions. Run Software Updates if you don't already have it.

Comment: This was actually introduced sometime during Safari 13 - I recall being hugely irritated when I went down the list sorting out all my legacy passwords - it would keep locking itself over & over, whether I was interacting with it or not. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/370721/85275